# I Can not install apk files on device or emulator in ADT-15.0.0?

Tags: android, adt, android-install-apk

I was developing my app and everything was OK. I installed ADT - 15.0.0 and installer_r15-windows.exe. After that, when I press Ctrl+F11 my project is uploaded but stayed in installing state without any progress. Why? can anybody help me?

thanks,

```
[2011-11-05 17:24:31 - order] ------------------------------
[2011-11-05 17:24:31 - order] Android Launch!
[2011-11-05 17:24:31 - order] adb is running normally.
[2011-11-05 17:24:31 - order] Performing org.mabna.order.ui.ActLogin activity launch
[2011-11-05 17:24:31 - order] Automatic Target Mode: using device '380700042ffa097'
[2011-11-05 17:24:31 - order] Uploading order.apk onto device '380700042ffa097'
[2011-11-05 17:24:33 - order] Installing order.apk...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated eclipse and the problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
[2011-11-05 17:24:31 - order] Automatic Target Mode: using device '380700042ffa097'
```

According to this line from the console log that you provided, this is not an emulator, this is an actual device. If you are trying to deploy to a device, make sure you have the right adb driver installed, if you are trying to deploy to an emulator create an AVD using the AVD manager.

Comment: I have tested it on both real device and emulator. before installing ADT 15.0.0 **everything was OK** and my app installed correctly. After installation of new version I encountered this problem.

Comment: I highly suggest you to update your development tools.  1)In eclipse Go to Help -> Check for updates.  2)Using your current ADT, open up the SDK manager and make sure you have installed the the Android SDK tools Rev 15 and Android SDK platform tools 9. 3) Make sure you have the most updated Android SDK from the [Android developer website](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).  I think this should fix your problems, it is just a matter of updating all your development environment tools.[More Info here](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Developer-Tools/ADT-Plugin-for-Eclipse.shtml)

Comment: I am having the same problem. Is there any solution? Can I revert back to previous revision? One revision fixes some issues but introduce more issues that we fixed in the previous ones

Answer (score 0):

launch an emulator first, or better yet, disconnect your android device if you want to launch your app in an emulator. eclipse should launch the correct emulator for you (assuming you created a compatible one already)

Comment: I have tested it on both real device and emulator. before installing ADT 15.0.0 **everything was OK** and my app installed correctly. After installation of new version I encountered this problem.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Is there any solution? Can I revert back to previous revision? One revision fixes some issues but introduce more issues that we fixed in the previous ones